# Extract variable number of columns from beginning and end from a SAS dataset

Tags: sas

I am having a SAS dataset where I want to keep, let's say, the firt `2` columns and last `4` columns, so to speak. In other words, only columns from beginning and from end.

```
data test;
    input a b c d e f g h i j;
cards;
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
;
```

**Initial output:**
[image]

What I want is the following -

**Output desired:**

[image]

I checked on the net, people are trying something with `varnum`, as shown [`here`](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Deleting-variables-by-varnum/td-p/36444), but I can't figure out. I don't want to use `keep/drop`, rather I want an automated way to solve this issue.

Comment: Do you have sorted column names? How do you understand what variable first, and what second? Or it s just depends on their order in dataset?

Comment: Hi, It depends on the order in the dataset, just as in the question. First two columns will mean first two from left, `a,b` and last 6, for example, will mean last 6 from the right, `e,f,g,h,i,j`. My col names, by chance, are in alphabetical order, but that's irrelevant.

Comment: Why would you want to use the variable positions to have any meaning?  Shouldn't you want to select the variables based on what they are not where they are?

Comment: Well, my dataset is such that I get revenue data, with every new month appended at the column end and I need to take the last 12 months.

Comment: So how do you name these revenue variables? Shouldn't the name reflect the order?

Comment: I get the sas dataset from a third party. Column names are like `NOV_2018`, `DEZ_2018`, `JAN_2019` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know number of variables, you can use this macro(you should specify num of first variables and num of last variables to keep in data set, libname and name of dataset):

```
%macro drop_vars(num_first_vars,num_end_vars,lib,dataset); %macro d;%mend d;

proc sql noprint;;
    select sum(num_character,num_numeric) into:ncolumns 
    from dictionary.tables 
    where libname=upcase("&lib") and memname=upcase("&dataset");
    select name into: vars_to_drop separated by ',' 
    from dictionary.columns 
    where libname=upcase("&lib") and 
          memname=upcase("&dataset") and
          varnum between %eval(&num_first_vars.+1) and %eval(&ncolumns-&num_end_vars);
   alter table &lib..&dataset
   drop &vars_to_drop;
quit;

%mend drop_vars;

%drop_vars(2,3,work,test);
```

Dataset before macro execution:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
| a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j  |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
```

Dataset after macro execution:

```
+---+---+---+---+----+
| a | b | h | i | j  |
+---+---+---+---+----+
| 1 | 2 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
+---+---+---+---+----+
```

Comment: Hi, I have tweaked the code slightly, to make it more generic. You had hardcoded `memname='TEST'`, so I changed that and with argument as (2,3) we were getting 1 element from beginning and 4 from the end. I changed that.

Answer (score 2):

`%DOSUBL` can run code in a separate stream and be part of a code generation scheme at code submit (pre-run) time.

Suppose the requirement is to to slice the columns of a data set out based on meta data *column position* as indicated by `varnum` (i.e. *places*), and the syntax for *places* is:

- `p:q` to select the range of columns whose `varnum` position is between `p` and `q`
- multiple ranges can be specified, separated by spaces ()
- a single column position, `p`, can be specified
- negative values select the position downward from the highest position.
- also, the process should honor all incoming data set options specified, i.e. `keep= drop=`

All the complex logic for implementing the requirements *could* be done in pure macro code using only `%sysfunc` and data functions such as `open`, `varnum`, `varname`, etc... That code would be pretty unwieldy.

The selection of names from meta data can be cleaner using SAS features such as `Proc CONTENTS` and `Proc SQL` executed within `DOSUBL`.

Example:

Macro logic is used to construct (or map) the filtering criteria statement based on `varnum`.  Metadata retrieval and processing done with Procs.

```
%macro columns_slice (data=, places=);
  %local varlist temp index p token part1 part2 filter joiner;
  %let temp = __&sysmacroname._%sysfunc(monotonic());

  %do index = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&places,%str( )));
    %let token = %scan(&places,&index,%str( ));

    %if NOT %sysfunc(prxmatch(/^(-?\d+:)?-?\d+$/,&token)) %then %do;
      %put ERROR: &sysmacname, invalid places=&places;
      %return;
    %end;

    %let part1 = %scan (%superq(token),1,:);
    %let part2 = %scan (%superq(token),2,:);

    %if %qsubstr(&part1,1,1) = %str(-) %then 
      %let part1 = max(varnum) + 1 &part1;

    %if %length(&part2) %then %do;
      %if %qsubstr(&part2,1,1) = %str(-) %then 
        %let part2 = max(varnum) + 1 &part2;
    %end;
    %else
      %let part2 = &part1;

    %let filter=&filter &joiner (varnum between &part1. and &part2.) ;

    %let joiner = OR;
  %end;

  %put NOTE: &=filter;

  %if 0 eq %sysfunc(dosubl(%nrstr(
    options nonotes;
    proc contents noprint data=&data out=&temp(keep=name varnum);
    proc sql noprint;
      select name
        into :varlist separated by ' '
      from &temp
      having &filter
      order by varnum
      ;
      drop table &temp;
    quit;
  )))
  %then %do;&varlist.%end;
  %else
    %put ERROR: &sysmacname;

%mend;
```

Using the slicer

```
* create sample table for demonstration;
data lotsa_columns(label='A silly 1:1 merge');
  if _n_ > 10 then stop;

  merge 
    sashelp.class 
    sashelp.cars  
  ;
run;

%put %columns_slice (data=lotsa_columns, places=1:3);
%put %columns_slice (data=lotsa_columns, places=-1:-5);
%put %columns_slice (data=lotsa_columns, places=2:4 -2:-4 6 7 8);

1848      %put %columns_slice (data=lotsa_columns, places=1:3);
NOTE: FILTER=(varnum between 1 and 3)
Name Sex Age
1849      %put %columns_slice (data=lotsa_columns, places=-1:-5);
NOTE: FILTER=(varnum between max(varnum) + 1 -1 and max(varnum) + 1 -5)
Horsepower MPG_City MPG_Highway Wheelbase Length
1850      %put %columns_slice (data=lotsa_columns, places=2:4 -2:-4 6 7 8);
NOTE: FILTER=(varnum between 2 and 4) OR (varnum between max(varnum) + 1 -2 and max(varnum) + 1
-4) OR (varnum between 6 and 6) OR (varnum between 7 and 7) OR (varnum between 8 and 8)
Sex Age Height Make Model Type MPG_City MPG_Highway Wheelbase
```

Honoring options

```
data have;
  array x(100);
  array y(100);
  array z(100);
run;

%put %columns_slice (data=have(keep=x:), places=2:4 8:10 -2:-4 -25:-27 -42);

1858      %put %columns_slice (data=have(keep=x:), places=2:4 8:10 -2:-4 -25:-27 -42);
NOTE: FILTER=(varnum between 2 and 4) OR (varnum between 8 and 10) OR (varnum between max(varnum)
+ 1 -2 and max(varnum) + 1 -4) OR (varnum between max(varnum) + 1 -25 and max(varnum) + 1 -27) OR
(varnum between max(varnum) + 1 -42 and max(varnum) + 1 -42)
x2 x3 x4 x8 x9 x10 x59 x74 x75 x76 x97 x98 x99
```

Comment: Thanks Richard for your efforts, I will look into it.

Comment: It took me some time to understand it, but now it makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If the names follow a pattern just generate the list using the pattern.  So if the names look like month names you just need to know one month to generate the other.

```
%let last_month = '01JAN2019'd ;
%let first_var = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&last_month,-12),monyy7.);
%let last_var = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&last_month,-0),monyy7.);
data want;
  set have(keep= id1 id2 &first_var -- &last_var);
run;
```

If you cannot find a SAS function or format that generates the names in the style your variables use then write your own logic.

```
data _null_;
   array month_abbr [12] $3 _temporary_ ('JAN' 'FEB' 'MAR' 'APR' 'MAY' 'JUN' 'JUL' 'AUG' 'SEP' 'OKT' 'NOV' 'DEK' );
   last_month=today();
   first_month=intnx('month',last_month,-12);
   call symputx('first_var',catx('_',month_abbr[month(first_month)],year(first_month)));
   call symputx('last_var',catx('_',month_abbr[month(last_month)],year(last_month)));
run;
```

Comment: Your code seems good. The only things is that for it to serve my purpose, I need to change the names of 100s of month variables from `JAN_2019` to `01JAN2019` that they come in this date format. How can I change the variable names in a loop?

Comment: Why would you need to change the names of the variables?  Why not just change the cdoe that generates the names of the variables to use in the DROP= clause?

Comment: As I said, I get the SAS data from a third party and it's a SAS file. That's why I need to change the variable names. I am not generating the original dataset, just working on what I get.

Comment: They change HOW they name the variables with every delivery? How do you even now what the variable names mean if there is no pattern to them?

Comment: There is a pattern. Let's say the data at the beginning of `October, 19` had the columns in this order `...... AUG_2019, SEP_2019`. For the data coming at the beginning of `Nov, 19` will have `October, 19` column added as well. Like this `...... AUG_2019, SEP_2019, OKT_2019` (Names of columns are in German).

Comment: So calculate a date in the starting and ending month. Use that date to generate the variable name. There are functions to convert month numbers to names, but even if not there are only 12 month names your codes to know how to generate.

Comment: Though, the manner in which you are approaching this seems reasonable, but I can't understand the implementation. OK, I calculate `start_month` and `end_month` like with macro variables, as you did. Then if I need to select the range like - `&first_var -- &last_var`, my column names should be mapped to it and that I don't know how to do.

Comment: Added example that should work for `OKT_2018`. Just clean it up with the real German month abbreviations.